# How to iterate anonymous function inside each function in Knockout viewmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, anonymous-function

I am building a Knockout viewmodel. The model has some fields like `dateFrom`, `DateTo`, `Status` and so forth. In addition, there is a list of `invoices`.

The invoices have some pricing information, which is a `price` object. My main object also have a price object, which should iterate all the invoice objects and find the total price.

**My problem is the following:**

The code runs smooth, until I add the following in my view:

```
<label data-bind="text:totalPrice().price().priceExVat"></label>
```

Here I get an:

```
TypeError: $(...).price is not a function
```

Which refers to my:

```
exVat += $(ele).price().priceExVat;
```

I don't understand it, because in my each function, I should have the element. The element have a `price()` function, so why would it not work? Is it some scope issue?

**My viewmodel:**

```
function invoice(invoiceDate, customerName, pdfLink, status) {
    var self = this;
    self.pdfLink = pdfLink;
    self.print = ko.observable(0);
    self.customerName = customerName;
    self.status = status;
    self.pdfPagesCount = function () {
        return 1;
    };
    self.invoiceDate = invoiceDate;

    self.price = function () {
        return new price(1.8, 2.1);
    };
}


function price(exVat, total) {
    var self = this;
    self.currency = '€';
    self.total = total;
    self.priceExVat = exVat;
    self.vatPercentage = 0.25;
    self.vatAmount = self.exVat - self.total;

    self.priceExVatText = function() {
        return self.priceExVat + ' ' + self.currency;
    };
}


var EconomicsViewModel = function (formSelector, data) {
    var self = this;
    self.dateFrom = data.dateFrom;
    self.dateTo = data.dateTo;


    self.invoices = ko.observableArray([
        new invoice('05-05-2014', 'LetterAmazer IvS', "http://www.google.com","not printed"),
        new invoice('05-05-2014', 'LetterAmazer IvS', "http://www.google.com", "not printed")
    ]);

    self.totalPrice = function () {
        var exVat = 0.0;
        $(self.invoices).each(function (index, ele) {
            console.log(ele);
            exVat += $(ele).price().priceExVat;
        });

        return price(exVat, 0);
    };
};
```

Comment: You're using jQuery to make jQuery DOM element wrappers out of things. You don't need jQuery anywhere in this code. Rewrite the totalPrice to something like the following: `self.totalPrice = ko.computed(function () {
        var exVat = 0.0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.invoices(), function(invoice){
            exVat += invoice.price().priceExVat;
        });
        return new price(exVat, 0);
    });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I read, `totalPrice` is actually a `price` object, you don't need to put a `.price()`:

```
<label data-bind="text:totalPrice().priceExVat"></label>
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry, there were also problems on your javascript:

```
self.totalPrice = function () {
    var exVat = 0.0;
    $(self.invoices()).each(function (index, ele) { //<-- add () to self.invoices to get the array
        console.log(ele);
        exVat += ele.price().priceExVat; //<-- remove useless jQuery
    });

    return new price(exVat, 0); //<-- add 'new'
};
```

Check **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqQVa/1/)**

**EDIT2:**

To answer [robert.westerlund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1105996/robert-westerlund)'s comment, you could remove `$().each` and replace with `ko.utils.arrayForEach` or even simpler use a `for` loop:

```
var arr = self.invoices();
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    exVat += arr[i].price().priceExVat;
}
```

Updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqQVa/2/)**

Comment: If I do that, so my code is "text:totalPrice().priceExVat", I just get the totalPrice() is undefined, which I don't understand as it is a part of the viewmodel

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard sorry, there were other problems too, I updated the answer

Comment: Really, there's no need for jQuery at all in the code. Knockout has the `ko.utils.arrayForEach` which does the same as what is being done with jQuery here. Perhaps it would be better to remove jQuery usage altogether from the view models?

Comment: Thanks so much. I also learned a lot seeing your changes + it works. Have a great saturday! :)

Comment: @robert.westerlund Both are just ways to get through an array, you could even do it with a simple for loop

Comment: Indeed and agreed, but since that is the only usage of another library in this code, I'd probably try to move to use the library which the code is already using a lot. Also, the `$(myarray)` does a lot of unnecessary things in creating a new object and stuff, so both the simple for loop and the `ko.utils.arrayForEach` (which is just a simple for loop, if you look at the code) would do less and achieve the same result. Still, just as you say, using jQuery works, I just feel it's really unnecessary. Just my two cents. :)

Comment: @robert.westerlund You are right. Updated the answer to use a `for` loop, the best way to have control on the code :)